# Count unique values in subquery

Tags: php, mysql, count, subquery

I am trying to count the unique values returned by a subquery using:

```
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT pm.id) FROM parts_manufacturers AS pm,
 parts_trading AS pt, enquiries 
 WHERE pm.id = pt.manufacturer AND pt.enquiryRef = enquiries.id 
 AND enquiries.entityRef = eo.id) AS manufacturers
```

But I'm getting the error:

```
General error: 2014 Cannot execute queries while other unbuffered queries are active
```

Which I have never seen before.

I can't use group by to eliminate duplicates either because it will make the subquery return more than 1 row.

Where am I going wrong and how do I count only unique values in my subquery?

---

When I try running it in phpmyadmin I get an out of memory error:

```
#5 - Out of memory (Needed 268435428 bytes)
```

---

Here is the full query:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS eo.id, name, eia.county, $valueColumn $averageColumn
                        (SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', entity_contacts.name, entity_contacts.lastName) FROM entity_contacts WHERE entityRef = eo.id AND isPrimary = 1 LIMIT 1) AS contact,
                        (SELECT ect.tel FROM entity_contacts AS ec, entity_contacts_telephones AS ect WHERE ect.contactRef = ec.id AND entityRef = eo.id AND ec.isPrimary = 1 LIMIT 1) AS tel,
                         countries.country AS countryName, CONCAT('images/flags/',LOWER(countryCode),'.gif') AS country, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM enquiries WHERE entityRef = eo.id) AS enquired,
                         (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM enquiries, jobs WHERE enquiries.id = jobs.enquiryRef AND entityRef = eo.id AND jobs.stateRef != 5) AS jobCount,
                         ept.term AS paymentTerms, ei.type,
                         (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT pm.id) as colname
                         FROM parts_manufacturers AS pm 
                        left outer join  parts_trading AS pt on pm.id = pt.manufacturer 
                        left outer join  enquiries on  pt.enquiryRef = enquiries.id
                         WHERE enquiries.entityRef = eo.id) AS manufacturers
                         FROM entity_details AS eo
                         LEFT JOIN entity_invoice_addresses AS eia ON eo.id = eia.entityRef AND eia.isPrimary = 1
                         LEFT JOIN countries ON eia.countryRef = countries.id
                         LEFT JOIN entity_industry_types AS ei ON ei.id = eo.industryTypeRef
                         LEFT JOIN entity_payment_terms AS ept ON eo.paymentTermsRef = ept.id,
                         users
                         WHERE eo.typeRef = 3
                         AND eo.deleted = 0
                         AND eo.ownerRef = users.id
                         LIMIT ?, ?
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont from where to come eo.id..

so , please clarify and reply :

```
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT pm.id) as colname
         FROM parts_manufacturers AS pm 
        left outer join  parts_trading AS pt on pm.id = pt.manufacturer 
        left outer join  enquiries  on  pt.enquiryRef = enquiries.id
         WHERE enquiries.entityRef = eo.id) AS manufacturers
```

---

please try it : i change user to joining table :--->

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS eo.id, name, eia.county, $valueColumn $averageColumn
                        (SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', entity_contacts.name, entity_contacts.lastName) FROM entity_contacts WHERE entityRef = eo.id AND isPrimary = 1 LIMIT 1) AS contact,
                        (SELECT ect.tel FROM entity_contacts AS ec, entity_contacts_telephones AS ect WHERE ect.contactRef = ec.id AND entityRef = eo.id AND ec.isPrimary = 1 LIMIT 1) AS tel,
                         countries.country AS countryName, CONCAT('images/flags/',LOWER(countryCode),'.gif') AS country, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM enquiries WHERE entityRef = eo.id) AS enquired,
                         (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM enquiries, jobs WHERE enquiries.id = jobs.enquiryRef AND entityRef = eo.id AND jobs.stateRef != 5) AS jobCount,
                         ept.term AS paymentTerms, ei.type,
                         (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT pm.id) as colname
                         FROM parts_manufacturers AS pm 
                        left outer join  parts_trading AS pt on pm.id = pt.manufacturer 
                        left outer join  enquiries on  pt.enquiryRef = enquiries.id
                         WHERE enquiries.entityRef = eo.id) AS manufacturers
                         FROM entity_details AS eo
                         LEFT outer JOIN entity_invoice_addresses AS eia ON eo.id = eia.entityRef AND eia.isPrimary = 1
                         LEFT outer JOIN countries ON eia.countryRef = countries.id
                         LEFT outer JOIN entity_industry_types AS ei ON ei.id = eo.industryTypeRef
                         LEFT outer JOIN entity_payment_terms AS ept ON eo.paymentTermsRef = ept.id,
                         LEFT outer JOIN users ON eo.ownerRef = users.id                          
                         WHERE eo.typeRef = 3
                         AND eo.deleted = 0                       
                         LIMIT ?, ?
```

Comment: dont you mean:
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT pm.id) as colname
        FROM parts_manufacturers AS pm 
       left outer join  parts_trading AS pt on pm.id = pt.manufacturer 
       left outer join  enquiries on  pt.enquiryRef = enquiries.id
        WHERE enquiries.entityRef = eo.id) AS manufacturers
In which case gives me the same error.

Comment: External column, it could be 316 for instance.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17810/discussion-between-vikram-jain-and-imperium2335)